# How to call a JS function from Flutter Web?

Tags: javascript, function, dart, flutter-web

I have a simple JS function that I want to call from a Flutter web application:

```
<script>
    function alertMessage(text) {
          alert(text)
    }
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

main.dart:

```
void onTap(){
    ///This is where I want to call the JS function...  alertMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [dart:js library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-js/dart-js-library.html)

```
import 'dart:js';

main() => context.callMethod('alert', ['Hello from Dart!']);
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) package. I had a few problems with [dart:js](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-js/dart-js-library.html) when I had to run tests, so this one worked as a great replacement.

```
import 'package:universal_html/js.dart';

context.callMethod("functionName", ['args']);
```